# Crystal Reports: Need to use a summary field as part of the Record Selection Formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a fairly basic report that needs to show events with a total spend of >$200K OR event attendance >60ppl.  The attendance portion is no problem, as it's a simple text field in the table.  The expense spend is a field that has to be summed before it can be used, coming from a separate table with multiple entries per event. I have no problem doing this in a summary field dropped in the eventID header or even using a subreport and passing a shared variable to the main report.  The problem I run into is that I cannot access this summary field in the report record selection to extract the either or records.  Any idea how I can do this accurately?

Comment: Please post some code. Also, what solutions have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

- Create a sql-expression field for total spending:

```
//{%total_spending}
(
  SELECT sum(Amount)
  FROM   Meeting_Expenses
  WHERE  MeetingId=Meeting.Id
)
```

- Use fields in record-selection formula:

```
{Meeting.actual_attendance}>60
AND {%total_spending}>200000
```

Comment: When I do the first part, I receive the error in compiling sql expression, failed to open a rowset...what's wrong?
(
  SELECT count({Meeting.ActualAttendance})
  FROM   Meeting
  WHERE  id=Meeting.MeetingID
)

Comment: Post the actual table and field names in your question and I'll update my answer.

Comment: The select statement above contains my actual fields or at least some of them:
     tblMeeting
     tblMeeting_Expenses
     Meeting.MeetingID 
     Meeting.Actual Attendance
     Meeting_Expenses.Amount